# How to handle page refresh, in a React app, using react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I would like to know what why is that I am getting the error: `GET http://localhost:8080/employees 404 (Not Found)`

My app is a simple react app, that when a user logs in, the user will be redirected to the initial page(lets call it root), which has a navbar with 4 links to other pages(same app, different pages).
So when the user navigates to the other links/pages present in the navbar, for example, the page/component employees, the page displays just fine, with no problem. But when the user clicks the refresh button of the browser, the error mentioned above is thrown.
I am using react-router-dom, react-redux, axios. I suspect the problem is in my react-router-dom set up. But not very sure.

```
// index.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```
// App.jsx
function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Function to handle user login
  const handleLogin = () => {
    dispatch(login());
  };

  // Function to handle user logout
  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  };

  // For security reasons, we need to check if the token is still valid when the user refreshes the page
  // We could use `localStorage` to store the login state, but it is not secure
  useEffect(() => {
    const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");

    if (!refresh_token) {
      navigate("/");
      return;
    }
    // Send a request to the server to check if the token is still valid
    axiosInstance
      .get("/auth/refresh", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${refresh_token}`,
        },
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(login());
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // If the token is not valid, redirect the user to the login page and clear the local storage
        navigate("/login");
        localStorage.clear();
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }, [dispatch, navigate]);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <Route path="/" element={<Root onLogout={handleLogout} />}>
          <Route index element={<Topics />} />
          <Route path="employees" element={<EmployeeList />} />
          <Route path="employees/create" element={<RegisterEmployee />} />
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
      ) : null}
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the index.js page, i tried HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter, and it worked fine, but it adds a "#" in the URL`http://localhost:8080/#/employees`, which is not the desired result. But somehow refreshing the page is working fine.

Comment: How are you building the app and serving/hosting it locally? How are you navigating to other pages? Seems like whatever you are using isn't serving the root index.html file for all page requests into the app.

Comment: Yes locally. Navigating the pages using react-router-dom.

Comment: Yes, we already knew the app was running locally, but I asked ***how*** you have built app, and ***how*** you are running it locally.

Answer (score -2):

It's because you are hosting your build files as traditional web.
React is single page app, so your nginx or apache whatever you using you should make sure all other app paths are serving through index.html